# How deals Surface Pro 3 with HD monitors?

Tags: resolution, microsoft-surface-pro

I've seen some  videos on youtube where the Surface Pro 3 is connected on 4K monitors and it is working pretty good. I do not know very much about 4k technology and how the Intel HD graphics processor deals with such resolution, but I have a Dell Ultrasharp u2711 ( 2560x1440 ) and my current laptop (Lenovo IdeaPad z580) cannot support such resolution via HDMI channel, just 1920x1080, currently I'm using VGA channel as it supports it's best 2048x1152, I'm disappointed on that, but is my problem as I did not consult someone before buying the monitor.
So, my question is: **Will the Surface Pro 3 support the native resolution of Dell u2711 already by using the Mini DisplayPort?**
Also, if anyone knows a solution to set-up the monitor native resolution on my IdeaPad z580, I've checked Google, but all say that this is a graphic card problem ( in my case HD4000 ).

Thank you

Comment: The surface pro 3 has one of the highest performance mobile Haswell chips on it.  Which one does your lenovo have?

Comment: Hi Ramhound, Thank you for the answer.
Here are the specifications of my current Lenovo computer: http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/ideapad/z-series/z580/#techspecs
I posses the i7 version

Comment: Its an Ivybridge product.  Whats your question now?  Likewise the SP3 has a 4650U which means HD5000 GPU.  SP3 graphical capabilities is better by a good margin

Comment: Answering your question about your IdeaPad, you'll unable to get 2560x1440 on your display via HDMI. It is a restriction of the display itself (ancient HDMI version). Resolution this high is available via DVI or DisplayPort only for this Dell.

Comment: Thank you, as I understand there is the problem with the HDMI version. I've tested on a MacBook Pro with Retina via HDMI channel and same problem, up to 1920/1080; and it was interesting for me, because the MacBook Pro has retina, so that's why I thought that may be because of the HDMI channel.

Answer (score 5):

Surface Pro 3 can drive up to **three** external displays. As you asking about just single, here is excerpt of my own edit on the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Surface_Pro_3#External_display_connectivity), slightly rephrased:

`In a single external display mode over DisplayPort, the i5 and i7-based models support resolutions up to 3840×2160 at 60 Hz, known as 4K Ultra HD.`

So yes, it's possible to connect your `2560×1440@60 Hz` Dell display to your Surface Pro 3 via Mini DisplayPort. You'll need either `Mini DisplayPort — DisplayPort` or `Mini DisplayPort — DVI-D DL` cable or suitable active adapter.

Comment: Thank you @TranslucentCloud, I just want to be sure before buying the Surface, because I don't want to make the same mistake twice.

Comment: Buy without any concern, it will work for you.